why in vscode wsl autoimport works extremely slowly?
When I try to use auto import in wsl he sometimes find the packages 3-5 seconds it is so long and so annoys, how to solve this problem?
On top sidebar vscode show "progress bar" that he thinking and he thining 3-5 seconds
Can be it depends on "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths" ? or maybe from another settings?


Please ensure that the code is posted in text format, and not as a screenshot.

python.analysis.packageIndexDepths misconfiguration could lead to decreased performance as too many modules are being indexed.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
